# Easy way to compile project using OpenNI OpenCV and PCL on OS X

Tags: xcode, opencv, cross-compiling, openni, point-cloud-library

I need to create project that uses OpenNI OpenCV and PCL on OS X. I have all stuff installed. I've checked that by running samples of OpenNI, NITE and PCL. 
I searched a lot about compiling all together but only can find separate explanations. Also there're a lot of questions unanswered. I've also tried to compile and work with Xcode 4.5 but the tutorials I've found are about old versions of Xcode. And the one I've found for Xcode 4 doesn't work.

There're 3 ways to compile as I understand. CMakeLists, Makefile, Xcode.

As I said, I'm able to compile PCL example with cmake as described the "Using PCL in your own project" guide. I'm also able to compile the OpenNI xxx sample just entering the src dir and calling 'make'.

But how to integrate it all together? I need to somehow merge both makefiles? There're a lot of instructions I don't understand.

Maybe I need more the Xcode way because I will probably debug.

What I do wrong and how to add OpenCV and PCL here?

I create new project Commandline Tool c++ type.

[image] 
[image]

Then add files from sample dir [image]
[image]



[image]

I've deleted main.cpp

Config:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Build
[image]

1 error here 

[image]

```
.../Samples/NiViewer/Draw.h:31:10: 'GL/gl.h' file not found
```

Comment: what's wrong with using CMake ?

Comment: Help me to construct it right way please

Comment: were you able to do it?

Comment: yes. I finally used CMakeLists.txt and then export for Xcode project.